# Fundamentals of mathematics

Tags: axioms

When I was a teenager, I always thought that mathematical results/theorems constitute absolute truths. However after having studied maths in college, I’ve came across axioms, and things like the continuum hypothesis.
When I first read that the continuum hypothesis is independent of ZFC: it can be neither proven nor disproven within the context of that axiom system. It blew my mind. I always thought that there was only one theory of maths. And that any proposition can be shown to be true or false. I also encountered the axiom of choice quite a bit in my studies. And learned that it is also independent from ZF theory.

I have finished college now, and I think I have more time to delve deeper into this subject. So I have compiled a list of things that I guess are kinda related, and that I want to learn more about :

- What are the different axioms behind arithmetic, real analysis, topology, algebra, measure theory, probability, geometry (I know a little about this one : Euclide’s axioms).
- Logical / non logical axioms.
- axiomatic systems/ formal systems
- ontology / epistemology of mathematics
- philosophy of mathematics
- I remember vaguely that there are two school of thoughts about mathematical objects/concepts : They exist independently of the human mind, and all we do is discover them/ They exist solely in the human mind, they are a creation of the mind. I am interested about this as well.
- maths and metaphysics
- decidability/undecidability in logic
- mathematical “paradoxes” like the Banach Tarski theorem.
- godel’s completeness theorem
- I also remember reading that Bertrand Russel has discovered some inconsistencies in earlier set theories which led to their refinement. And then Kurt Godel proving that ZFC is a consitent theory (how on earth can you prove that no matter what you try you won’t get inconsistencies ?).

These things deeply fascinate me. And I would like to know where to start to learn about them. If you can suggest a list of courses/ books ranked in increasing difficulty, that would be great.

PS : I have studied the basics in these theories : arithmetic, real analysis, topology, algebra, measure theory, probability, geometry.

Comment: Godel **never** proved that ZFC is consistent. That said, I'm glad you are interested in logic, so you're welcome to [the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/44058/logic). You may also be interested to browse the posts I linked from my profile. In particular, under "Logic Texts" you may find suitable free texts from which you can learn logic from.